# Activity dialog small and empty on Android 5

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-theme

I have an activity

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices_list);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
}
```

and in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.DeviceListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
```

To open it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,
            BluetoothDeviceListActivity.class)
startActivity(intent)
```

On my Samsung Galaxy Tab A Android 7.0 it works perfectly, the activity is opened as a dialogue, and I can see the content.

[image: Working on Samsung Tablet]

But I'm trying it on an emulator (WSVGA_7) Runing Android 5.2 and the dialog is very small and empty blank.

[image: Not working on 5.2]

How can I make the Dialog activity appear the same for all android versions and not show as blank? I also tried using Activity instead of AppCompatActivity but same issue.

Thank you

EDIT:

HEre's the layout file for the activity: activity_devices_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scan_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/unit_16_text"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/scan"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@id/scan_button"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listViewDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/scan_button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/scan_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/settings_printers_connection_settings"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you post your R.layout.activity_devices_list file?

Comment: @TarasAntoshchuk Added the layout. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` in your activity's `onCreate` method.

Comment: I tried that but now the screen is all white. The dialog spanned all the screen but the content is missing.